# How can I collect all weapons in Raid Mode?

Tags: ps4, resident-evil-revelations-2

There is record for collecting all weapons in Raid Mode in RE:Revelations 2:

> Weapon Wizard  -- Get all weapons. (Any level/tag)

I thought that's not that hard and started collecting weapons which drop randomly from missions. When I thought that I'm done, I didn't get the record. After checking [wiki page](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Raid_Mode_(Revelations_2)) I found out, that I'm missing Shotgun Drake, Rifle Muramasa and Pale Rider. But I've never seen such things in game!

I'm playing free version of game which contains only Episode 1.

How can I get these weapons? Do I need to purchase additional episodes or DLC? Or are these event rewards weapons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to complete this achievement: I purchased [Resident Evil Revelations 1 & 2 Bundle](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0102-CUSA06314_00-B000000000007331), looks like it contains Deluxe editions of RE:R2. After that those rare weapons began to appear in in-game store.